# GridView | drop down lists gets unpopulate

Tags: asp.net

The Drop Down Lists in the FooterTemplate gets unpopulate  when clicking "update" on some row
this is the page load event when they gets populate:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlImages_new = ((DropDownList)gvAdminArticleAdd.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlImages_new"));
        ddlImages_new.DataSource = GetPdfs();
        ddlImages_new.DataBind();

        DropDownList ddl_invNamesNew = ((DropDownList)gvAdminArticleAdd.FooterRow.FindControl("ddl_invNamesNew"));
        ddl_invNamesNew.DataSource = GetInvestigatorNames();
        ddl_invNamesNew.DataBind();
    }
```

If I click the update linkButton on some row the data in the drop down lists are disappear
Even when try to call the page load on cancel event it didn't work.

```
  protected void gvAdminArticleAdd_CancelEditEventHandler(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
    {
        Page_Load(sender, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bind your controls only when the page is not post back:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList ddlImages_new = ((DropDownList)gvAdminArticleAdd.FooterRow.FindControl("ddlImages_new"));
        ddlImages_new.DataSource = GetPdfs();
        ddlImages_new.DataBind();

        DropDownList ddl_invNamesNew = ((DropDownList)gvAdminArticleAdd.FooterRow.FindControl("ddl_invNamesNew"));
        ddl_invNamesNew.DataSource = GetInvestigatorNames();
        ddl_invNamesNew.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nope still don't work. when I click the update the ddl are getting clear and when hitting "cancel" they are remaining empty.
Any other idea?